# How to concatenate every k binary value of a cell array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a cell-array 1x20000 of binary values and I want concatenate every 4 elements and store it in an array.

For example I have:

```
v={'0','0','1','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','1','0','1','‌​0','0'}
```

I want get:

```
v1=[0011,'0010'...]
```

Is that possible? If yes, how can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output.

Comment: For example i have v={'0','0','1','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','1','0','1','0','0'} i want get  v1={'0011','0010'...}

Comment: or v=[0011,0010...]

Comment: Please put updates in your question using [edit]. I'm having a bit of difficulty right now because your sample cell array has stray characters in it (the resulting array has 22 characters rather than the expected 16).

Comment: `cell2mat(reshape(C,5000,4));` should do it, to reshape a cell array `C` of single character digits stored as strings in a cell array C into 4 character strings over 5000 rows

Comment: @Wolfie You don't even need `cell2mat` if you use `[v{:}]`, but the sample provided has extended ascii characters in it, so the length of the resulting array is not divisible by 4.

Comment: @Wolfie thanks for your answer i trayed that and i get a matrix

Comment: @Dia Your desired output `v1` looks like you want a matrix. If that's not what you want, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
v={'0','0','1','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','1','0','1','0','0'}
```

You can convert the cell array to a vector and reshape:

```
>> a = reshape([v{:}], 4, []).'
a =

0011
1001
0001
0100
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if i do that i get a matrix but i want concatenate elements to get classes because i have to implement poker test for random numbers

Comment: I'm really not clear on what output you're looking for. `a(1,:)` will give you the string `0011`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: I have a sequence of 20 000 bits, i have to split this sequence in segments of 4 bits (5000 segments) and count the frequence of occurrence of every segments and store the result in an array f[i] which  i refer to segments. This is part of my code:
    z=dec2bin(s); %S sequence of integer random numbers(matrix 1x2000)
    v=reshape(z',1,[]); 
    liste=num2cell(v);

Comment: In that case, I don't understand why you're converting to binary at all. You should be able to count the frequency more easily using the integer. Also, reshaping would be unnecessary if you had used `z = dec2bin(s.')` (assuming `s` contains values from [0..15]).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback^^.My generator generate unique integer values, so i have to convert to binary to get a sequence which i can split it to segments and count frequence of occurence.

Comment: There's no difference between an integer value and its binary representation. Please update your question with your actual requirements.